# Change in model for a p-dropdown placed in table cell in all columns changes the value for p-dropdwon in another row for the same column

Tags: dynamic, nested, dropdown, primeng, model-binding

Attached is the image to show how is the data been shown in table.
I have a nested json object like below. the main object i am showing as a row in prime ng table and on click of row expand of the row i am showing the data under description attribute in again a primeng table.

```
{
    "Installed":[
       {
          "id":"1#2",
          "Operational_State":"Installed",
          "A Sne-Shelf":"20917118-CN32SLOT",
          "A Slot-Card":"SLOT-1-MOTR",
          "Z Sne-Shelf":"20917120-CN32SLOT",
          "Z Slot-Card":"SLOT-1-MOTR",
          "Optical End":"20917118:1-3-1:20917120:1-2-1",
          "Channel Capacity":"194.60-100GB",
          "A Slot Available":"2",
          "Z Slot Available":"1",
          "Capacity Available":"40",
          "Description":[
             {
                "id":"1#2#1",
                "A_end":[
                   {
                      "A_Equipment":20917117,
                      "A_Position":[
                         "1-6-2-1"
                      ],
                      "A_Status":"Potential",
                      "A_FORECASTED_SFP":[
                         "XFP 1310",
                         "SFP",
                         "gp"
                      ]
                   }
                ],
                "Z_end":[
                   {
                      "Z_Equipment":20917119,
                      "Z_Position":[
                         "1-3-2-1"
                      ],
                      "Z_Status":"Installed",
                      "Z_FORECASTED_SFP":[
                         "SFP 1310"
                      ]
                   }
                ]
             },
             {
                "id":"1#2#2",
                "A_end":[
                   {
                      "A_Equipment":20917117,
                      "A_Position":[
                         "1-6-1-1"
                      ],
                      "A_Status":"Potential",
                      "A_FORECASTED_SFP":[
                         "XFP 1310",
                         "SFP",
                         "gp"
                      ]
                   }
                ],
                "Z_end":[
                   {
                      "Z_Equipment":20917119,
                      "Z_Position":[
                         "1-3-1-1"
                      ],
                      "Z_Status":"Installed",
                      "Z_FORECASTED_SFP":[
                         "SFP 1310"
                      ]
                   }
                ]
             },
             {
                "id":"1#2#3",
                "A_end":[
                   {
                      "A_Equipment":20917117,
                      "A_Position":[
                         "1-6-3-1"
                      ],
                      "A_Status":"Installed",
                      "A_FORECASTED_SFP":[
                         "XFP 1310"
                      ]
                   }
                ],
                "Z_end":[
                   {
                      "Z_Equipment":20917119,
                      "Z_Position":[
                         "1-3-3-1"
                      ],
                      "Z_Status":"Potential",
                      "Z_FORECASTED_SFP":[
                         "XFP 1310",
                         "SFP",
                         "MOTR"
                      ]
                   }
                ]
             },
             {
                "id":"1#1#1",
                "A_end":[
                   {
                      "A_Equipment":20917117,
                      "A_Position":[
                         "1-6-2-1"
                      ],
                      "A_Status":"Potential",
                      "A_FORECASTED_SFP":[
                         "XFP 1310",
                         "SFP",
                         "gp"
                      ]
                   },
                   {
                      "A_Equipment":20917117,
                      "A_Position":[
                         "1-6-1-1"
                      ],
                      "A_Status":"Potential",
                      "A_FORECASTED_SFP":[
                         "XFP 1310",
                         "SFP",
                         "gp"
                      ]
                   },
                   {
                      "A_Equipment":20917117,
                      "A_Position":[
                         "1-6-3-1"
                      ],
                      "A_Status":"Installed",
                      "A_FORECASTED_SFP":[
                         "XFP 1310"
                      ]
                   }
                ],
                "Z_end":[
                   {
                      "Z_Equipment":20917119,
                      "Z_Position":[
                         "1-3-2-1"
                      ],
                      "Z_Status":"Installed",
                      "Z_FORECASTED_SFP":[
                         "SFP 1310"
                      ]
                   }
                ]
             }
          ]
       }
    ]
}
```

html for the same

```
 <p-table #dt [columns]="selectedColumns2" sortField="Operational_State" [resizableColumns]="true" (onFilter)="onFilter($event, dt)" columnResizeMode="expand" responsive="true" [defaultSortOrder]="-1"
  [ngStyle]="{'width': 'auto'}"  columnResizeMode="fit" selectionMode="single" [autoLayout]="true" [scrollable]="false" [value]="details" dataKey="id"
  [paginator]="paginatorPlanned" [rows]="30" [(selection)]="selectedRecord" (onRowSelect)="onRowSelect($event)">
  <ng-template pTemplate="caption" let-columns>
    <div class="ui-helper-clearfix row" style="width:100%;">
      <div class="col-md-4" [ngStyle]="{'text-align':'left'}">
        <!-- <p-multiSelect [options]="cols" [(ngModel)]="selectedColumns2" optionLabel="header" maxSelectedLabels=0 selectedItemsLabel="{0} columns selected"
          [ngStyle]="{minWidth: '200px'}" defaultLabel="Choose Columns">
        </p-multiSelect> -->
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-2"></div>
      <div class="col-md-6 ml-0" [ngStyle]="{'text-align':'right'}">
        <button type="button" (click)="onResetAll($event, dt,dt1)" class="btn bt-button" [ngStyle]="{'margin-right': '0.5em','height': '35px'}">

          <Span>Clear Filter</Span>
        </button>
        <button type="button" (click)="exportToExcel()" [ngStyle]="{'margin-right':'0.5em'}" class="btn bt-button ml-4">
          <i class="fa fa-file-excel-o mr-2" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          <span>Export</span>
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- <div>
      <table>
        <tr>
          <th></th>
                <th *ngFor="let col of selectedColumns2" [ngSwitch]="col.field" [ngStyle]="{'overflow': 'visible'}">
          
                  <p-multiSelect #cmp *ngSwitchCase=col.field [options]=col.options defaultLabel="Select Items" (onChange)="dt.filter($event.value, col.field, 'in');updateFilter(dt,$event.value,col.field);"
                    selectedItemsLabel="{0} item selected" maxSelectedLabels=0 [(ngModel)]="selectedItem[col.field]" defaultLabel="Select Items"
                    (onChange)="dt.filter($event.value, col.field, 'in')" selectedItemsLabel="{0} item selected" maxSelectedLabels=0
                    [styleClass]="selectedItem[col.field]!=null ? 'ui-default-label' : ''"></p-multiSelect>
                </th>
                  </tr>
      </table>

      </div> -->
 
  </ng-template>
  <ng-template pTemplate="header" let-columns>
    <tr [ngStyle]="{'white-space':'nowrap'}">
      <th style="width: 3rem"></th>
      <th [ngStyle]="{'width':'auto'}" *ngFor="let col of columns" pReorderableColumn [pSortableColumn]="col.field" pResizableColumn>
        {{col.header}}
        <p-sortIcon [field]="col.field" ariaLabel="Activate to sort" ariaLabelDesc="Activate to sort in descending order" ariaLabelAsc="Activate to sort in ascending order"></p-sortIcon>
      </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th></th>
    <th *ngFor="let col of columns" [ngSwitch]="col.field" [ngStyle]="{'overflow': 'visible'}">

      <p-multiSelect #cmp *ngSwitchCase=col.field [options]=col.options defaultLabel="Select Items" (onChange)="dt.filter($event.value, col.field, 'in');updateFilter(dt,$event.value,col.field);"
        selectedItemsLabel="{0} item selected" maxSelectedLabels=0 [(ngModel)]="selectedItem[col.field]" defaultLabel="Select Items"
        (onChange)="dt.filter($event.value, col.field, 'in')" selectedItemsLabel="{0} item selected" maxSelectedLabels=0
        [styleClass]="selectedItem[col.field]!=null ? 'ui-default-label' : ''"></p-multiSelect>

    </th>
  </tr>
  </ng-template>
 
  <ng-template pTemplate="body" let-rowData let-columns="columns" let-expanded="expanded" let-rowIndex="rowIndex">
      <tr *ngIf="rowGroupMetadata[rowData.Operational_State].index === rowIndex">
        <td></td> 
        <td colspan="10">
              <span class="p-text-bold p-ml-2" [class]="'route-badge-status-' + rowData.Operational_State">
                {{rowData.Operational_State | uppercase}}
              </span>
          </td>

          <!-- <button type="button" pButton pRipple [pRowToggler]="rowData" class="p-button-text p-button-rounded p-button-plain p-mr-2" [icon]="expanded ? 'pi pi-chevron-down' : 'pi pi-chevron-right'"></button>
          <span class="p-text-bold p-ml-2">{{rowData.operational_state | uppercase}}</span> -->
      </tr>
  
 
    <tr [pSelectableRow]="rowData" [ngStyle]="{'white-space':'nowrap'}">
      <td>
        <button type="button" pButton  pRipple [pRowToggler]="rowData" class="p-button-text p-button-rounded p-button-plain" [icon]="expanded ? 'pi pi-chevron-down' : 'pi pi-chevron-right'" title="Expand"></button>
        <button pButton pRipple icon="pi pi-pencil" class="p-button-rounded p-button-warning ml-2" title="Draw" (click)="drawRoute(rowData)"></button>
      </td>
      <td *ngFor="let col of columns" class="ui-resizable-column">
        {{rowData[col.field]}}
      </td>
    </tr>
  </ng-template>
  <ng-template  pTemplate="rowexpansion" let-rowData>

<tr [ngStyle]="{'white-space':'nowrap'}">
  <td colspan="10"> 
    <div class="" style="display: flex;justify-content: space-around;">
      <div>
      <p-table #dt2 [value]="rowData.Description" dataKey="id" styleClass="p-datatable-striped" [ngStyle]="{'width': 'auto'}" [paginator]="false" [rows]="10" [columns]="selectedDetailColumns">
        <ng-template pTemplate="header">
          <!-- <tr>
            <th class="childHeader" colspan="3">ASNE</th>
            <th class="childHeader" colspan="3">ZSNE</th>
          </tr> -->
          <tr>
            <th class="childHeader" [ngStyle]="{'width':'auto'}" class="customheader1" *ngFor="let col of detailColumns" pReorderableColumn [pSortableColumn]="col.field" pResizableColumn>
              {{col.header}}
              <p-sortIcon [field]="col.field" ariaLabel="Activate to sort" ariaLabelDesc="Activate to sort in descending order" ariaLabelAsc="Activate to sort in ascending order"></p-sortIcon>
            </th>
          </tr>
        </ng-template>
        <ng-template pTemplate="body" let-detail let-rowIndex="rowIndex">
       <tr>
        <td *ngFor="let col of detailColumns; let i=index" class="ui-resizable-column">
          <div *ngIf="col.showDropdown" style="margin-left:-8px;">
            <!-- <p-dropdown #cmp1 [options]="initial?(detail|field:col:rowIndex): detail[col.subfield]" [(ngModel)]="detail[col.subfield]"
            id="{{detail.id}}_{{col.subfield}}"  scrollHeight="400px" appendTo="body" (onChange)="updateFields(dt2,$event,col,detail,rowIndex,rowData)"
            dataKey="value" [styleClass]="detail[col.field]!=null ? 'ui-default-label' : ''">
          </p-dropdown> -->
          <p-dropdown #cmp1 [options]="initial?(detail|field:col:rowIndex): selectedField[col.subfield]" [(ngModel)]="selectedRowCol[rowIndex]" optionValue="label"
            id="{{rowIndex}}_{{i}}_{{col.subfield}}"  scrollHeight="400px" appendTo="body" (onChange)="updateFields(dt2,$event,col,detail,rowIndex,rowData,i)"
            dataKey="value">
          </p-dropdown>
          </div>
          <div *ngIf="!col.showDropdown">
            <!-- <ng-container *ngFor="let item of detail[col.field]"> -->
              {{initial?(detail|field:col:rowIndex): selectedField[col.subfield]}}
      <!-- </ng-container>   -->
          </div> 
        </td>
       </tr>
        </ng-template>
      </p-table>
      </div>
    </div>
  </td>

</tr>

  </ng-template>
      </p-table>
```

I have created a forloop to display the dropdown in each row column cell. Initially data loads properly but when I change the value of one dropdown it changes the value for the same dropdown in another row.

Comment: Kindly suggest if i have done the dynamic model binding correctly or not as it is the nested object.

Comment: Any help will be appreciated